# Representation/meaning difference between religious icons in open street map?

Tags: openstreetmap, icon

I'm curious what the difference is between these two icons used in open street map. 
[image]
The cross clearly represents a christian church. 

Is the kneeling icon a more general religious icon representing building that isn't necessarily a church and/or christian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [OpenStreeMap wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:religion), it is a generic symbol for place of worship. As you have "Christian" in the name of your example, `religion` category of this POI should be set to `christian` - it is none right now, what can be easily checked using [Query feature](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/358849890).